# Apache Optimization: Frequent "Oops Not Found" error for my website

Tags: php, apache

**The problem:**
I a have a small web application (PHP/MySQL) that a client of mine uses. Often they have about 10-15 users in the same network that use the application. We have been noticing frequent "Oops not found" being displayed on their browsers.

**The diagnosis**
I am assuming it's Apache settings, as I have not seen this issue replicated on other networks. It's probably because of simultaneous connections being issued from the same IP.

I have tried enabling mpm in apache using by adding this code httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ServerLimit             250
    StartServers             10
    MinSpareThreads          75
    MaxSpareThreads         250 
    ThreadLimit              64
    ThreadsPerChild          32
    MaxClients             8000
    MaxRequestsPerChild   10000
</IfModule>
```

But I am still getting the same issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: If your application relies on URL rewriting, I would first look at how it handles the routing and/or if your application has some 'write' operations somewhere, during which any other request to the resource currently being written might generate an exception/error which would lead to the "Oops Not Fount" you see.

Comment: `Oops` it's a non-standard error response. It's like a joke clients virus or malware.

Comment: Couldn't it be issue of high latency? As in when multiple simultaneous connections connect from a single IP?

Comment: There is not enough information here to offer an accurate answer.  Is the "Oops not found" a 404? 500? Does your application use a front controller? Does it have broken links? What errors are being thrown in PHP?  What operating system, Apache version, and PHP build/version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the given information I'll try to answer the question.

If you get "Oops Not Fount" with about 10-15 users in the same network then there is a big issue in your code base. I have managed to handle more than 100 users simultaneously with Apache prefork without an issue in an enterprise scale application.

If you really think that Apache worker is going to solve your problem, see the link below. It has got all the configuration to be done.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1038416

Let me know if you need help.

Comment: It's a windows server. Also, could it be DNS issues?

Comment: With the given information I can't tell exactly what's the issue. It could be due to DNS